# Unicity of solution of pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let the pde $$\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=f(x)$$
The question is:

> Find the limit condition such that this pde admit a unique solution in $[a,b] \times [0,T].$

For this, I suppose the existence of to sulutions $u_1$ and $u_2$ and we put $v = u_1 - u_2.$ Then, $$\dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} - \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} = 0$$ 
myltiply this last equation by $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t}$ and we integrate over $[a,b]$ and we obtained $$\displaystyle\int_a^b \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} . \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} dx - \int_a^b\dfrac{\partial^2 v} {\partial t^2}. \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} dx = 0$$

I tried integration by parts, but didn't find the limit conditions to obtain the unicity of this pde. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the wave equation there is a conserved energy
$$
E(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (u_t)^2+(u_x)^2 dy.
$$
This is obtained multiplying by $u_t$ and integrating by parts (as you did). For $v$ this quantity is zero initially, thus it vanishes for all times. Right?

Comment: no, sorry I did not understand. how we continue the calculations of the integration by parts and how we deduce the limit conditions?

Comment: You have 
$$
\int u_{tt}u_t-\int u_tu_{xx}=\frac{1}{2}\int (u_{t})_t^2+\int u_{xt}u_{x}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\int (u_{t})_t^2+\frac{1}{2}\int (u_{x})^2_t=\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=0.
$$

Comment: As $E(0)=0$ you obtain that $v$ is a constant (and thus it vanishes)

Comment: but who are the limit conditions? please.

Comment: What do you mean by "limit condition"? I think that you refer to the conditions under the functional makes sense, right? In that case you need $H^1$, isn't it?

Comment: the limit conditions are y(a) , y(b) or y'(a) , y'(b) for exampl... Dirichlet, or Neuman??

Comment: Ok, you mean boundary conditions :-P. Well, in that case we have to check the boundary terms in the integration by parts that I made above. We get 
$$
\int_a^b u_tu_{xx}=u_tu_x|_{a}^b-\int_a^b u_{tx}u_x.
$$
Thus, you need to impose Neumann BC, right?

Comment: Slowly please, we have $$\int_a^b \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} . \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} dx - \int_a^b \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} . \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} dx = 0$$ then $$\int_a^b  \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} . \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} dx - [\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} . \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}]_a^b + \int_a^b \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} [\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}] . \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} dx = 0$$ and what are the other steps? please

Comment: why $$\dfrac{d}{dt} E(t)=0$$

Comment: Well, in the second line you have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b (u_t)^2+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b (u_x)^2-u_tu_x|_{a}^b=0.
$$
Now you impose Neumann BC ($u_x=0$ at the boundary) and you use the definition of $E$:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b (u_t)^2+(u_x)^2=\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=0.
$$

Comment: if we don't know definition of $E(t),$ How we can prouve that $$\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_a^b [\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}]^2 dx + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_a^b [\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}]^2 dx$$ if

Comment: It's the first line in my answer: 
$$
E(t)=\int_a^b (u_t)^2+(u_x)^2
$$

Comment: yes, but why if $E(0)=0$ then $E(t)=0$ for all $t?$ i don't understand this point please, then why $E$ depend only on $t?$ why she not depend on $x?$

Comment: Look, assume that you have two different solutions with the same BC and initial conditions. Define $v=u_1-u_2$. You have 
$$
E(t)=\int_a^b (v_t)^2+(v_x)^2=E(0)
$$ 
but initially you have $v(0,x)=0$ and $v_t(0,x)=0$ ($u_1, u_2$ has the same BC and initial conditions), thus $E(0)=0$, ok?

Comment: $E(t)$ depends only on time because you are integrating in $x$ (and this kill this dependence), and its derivative is zero due to the equation and the computation above.

Comment: Sorry i dont't understand the first point: $$E(t) = E(0)$$

Comment: $$
\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=0
$$
implies $E(t)$ is a constant. This constant is $E(0)$.

Comment: So, we have $E(t)=0$ so $\dfrac{d}{dt} E(t)=0$ so $E(t)=c$ for all $t,$ whith $c$ constante, then $E(t)=0$ it's okay?

Comment: Mmm you have $\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=0$ so $E(t)=E(0)=0$